# vspace in LoT vs. starred chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, vspace

EDIT: I originally thought it was `tocloft` that creates the space between different chapters in the LoT. I was wrong. I edited the title, but left the original question.

I'm currently facing the following problem: I'm using the `tocloft` package for my ToC, LoT and LoF. By default (?) it adds a vspace of 10pt between tables and figures of different chapters. However, this does not seem to work with starred chapters. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

    \listoftables

    \newpage

    \tableofcontents

    \newpage

    \chapter{This is chapter one}

    \begin{table}
        \caption[Table 1]{This is table 1}
    \end{table}


    \chapter{This is chapter two}

    \begin{table}
        \caption[Table 2]{This is table 2}
    \end{table}

    \chapter*{Appendix\markright{Appendix}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix} 
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
    \setcounter{table}{0}

    \begin{table}
        \caption[Appendix Table]{This is a table in the appendix.}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

And here's a screenshot showing the problem:

[image: Missing vspace in LoT]

As can be seen in the screenshot, the vspace between Table 2.1 and Table A1 is missing. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `\chapter` command that adds the space to the LoF and LoT but `\chapter*` does not do that. You could define a new macro to add the space and call it whenever you use `\chapter*`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\addloflotspace}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
}
% ...
\chapter*{No number}
\addloflotspace
This chapter ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter Wilson, this works like a charm. And sorry for "blaming" your tocloft package! :-) Apparently I was wrong in assuming that tocloft is responsible for the space in the LoT and the LoF! I edited the question!

Comment: @neacal No problem --- LaTeX internals can be confusing at (most of) times.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've been writing theses, reports, etc. with LaTeX for several years now and feel like I've only slightly scratched the surface of this powerful system. Before posting here I googled for quite a long time and could not find this seemingly basic source of my "problem". Where could I get such information (i.e. LaTeX internals)?

Comment: @neacal If you are a masochist start with https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base. Others may give you a more direct link to what you are after.